# Prove that the antichain of $\mathcal P(\{1,2,3,4\})$ of size $6$ is unique

Tags: combinatorics

Let $S=\{1,2,3,4\}$.

Consider the power set $\mathcal P(S)$ as a poset under the usual subset ordering.

Prove that the only antichain of $\mathcal P(S)$ of size $6$ is the antichain of all $2$-subsets of $S$.

An antichain is when two elements are incomparable. I'm not sure I understand what this means.

1. $\{1\},\{2,3\}$
2. $\{1,2\},\{1\}$

Is an antichain a set when the number of elements in each subsets is not strictly increasing(2)? Or is it when there are elements in a subset but one of those elements isn't in the previous subset(1)?

To prove this I know I need to assume the only antichain of $\mathcal P(S)$ of size $6$ is the antichain of all $3$-subsets of $S$.

Comment: The word "antichain" is meaningful in the context of a partially ordered set.  What is the partial order you're using?  Inclusion?

Comment: There are only $4$ $3$-subsets of $S$; there are $6$ $2$-subsets of $S$, however.

Answer (score 1):

If $(A,\le)$ is any partially ordered set, then two elements, $x$ and $y$, of $A$ are considered incomparable if $x\nleq y$ and $y\nleq x$.

In the case of a set of sets (such as the power set of a set), ordered by inclusion, two elements $x$ and $y$ are considered incomparable if $x\nsubseteq y$ and $y\nsubseteq x$.

Consider the antichains in $\mathcal P(S)$.

An antichain containing $\varnothing$ can only have one element, because the empty set is a subset of *every* set, and hence comparable to every other element.

An antichain containing $\{n\}$ can only have other elements in $\mathcal P(S\setminus\{n\})$. What is the largest antichain in there?

Keep thinking through the cases.

**Extra hint:** There's a sort of symmetry here that relates subsets of certain sizes to subsets of certain other sizes. Can you figure out what it is?

Answer (score 0):

Pick an antichain, there are 3 cases to consider:

1. If we have a 3-subset in the antichain, then the antichain will look like {abc, ad, bd, cd} or {abc, abd, adc, dbc}. So the size of the antichain is at most 4<6.
2. If we have a 1-subset in the antichain, then the antichain will look like {a, subsets of {b, c, d}}. So the size of the antichain will be at most $1+{3\choose 1}=4<6$.
3. If we have a 4-subset or no subset in the antichain, then the size of the antichain is 1<6.

Thus, the only possible antichain with cardinality 6 is the antichain of all 2-subsets of S.